# Add comma before last character of a string in c#

Tags: c#, string

I need to put a comma before the last char of a string.

For example:

Input: 101919  = Ouput: 10191,9

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: What is the length of the string, do you think? How might you insert a character? I wonder.

Comment: lets see an attempt please.

Comment: @Anthony: sometime 6 or 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the [insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) method

```
strTarget = strTarget.Insert( srtrTarget.Length -1, ",");
```

Answer (score 10):

```
if (input.Length > 0) { input = input.Insert(input.Length - 1, ","); }
```

Comment: @Maxime: In the case that `input.Length` is `0`, though, you probably want to do something… `else` (if the intended behaviour isn’t to do nothing).

Comment: Works as expected